# Using enhanced for-loop to retrieve data from two ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

I have a question about a (probably very) simple problem I've encountered in the code included.

The idea of the code is to list all customers, with their accounts, like my example below:

```
Customer 1

Account 1 balance
Account 2 balance


Customer 2

Account 3 balance
Account 4 balance
```

..and so on.
The problem is that the code used (shown below) works like intended with the first customer, showing all of it's accounts. But it stops there. So Customer 2 won't be printed out despite existing in the database.

```
public String allAccounts() {
    for (Customer customer : clients) {
        String clientInfo = "";
        clientInfo = clientInfo + customer.getCust() + "\n\n";
        for (Account account : customer.accounts) {
            clientInfo = clientInfo + account.getAccinfo() + "\n";
        }
        return clientInfo;
    }
    return "Not in use";
}
```

I might add that the customer.getCust gets the name of the customer, and that account.getAccinfo gets the account-number and balance of the account. And since it works as inteneded for the first customer I suppose it's a problem with the loop rather than the functions themselves.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Thanks a lot everybody for quick and good answers! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- init a `StringBuilder` E.g. `sb`  outside the `for(Customer ...` loop,
- change the `return clientInfo` into `sb.append(clientInfo)`
- replace `return "Not in use"` with `return sb.toString().length==0?"Not in use": sb.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

When you return something (`return clientInfo`), the method is 'done'.
You probably want to return `List<String>` instead, or `Map<String, String>`.

```
public List<String> allAccounts() {
    ArrayList<String> accounts = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Customer customer : clients) {
        String clientInfo = "";
        clientInfo = clientInfo + customer.getCust() + "\n\n";
        for (Account account : customer.accounts) {
            clientInfo = clientInfo + account.getAccinfo() + "\n";
        }
        accounts.add(clientInfo);
        continue;
    }
    accounts.add("Not in use");
    return accounts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify as below and try:

```
 public String allAccounts() {
        String clientInfo = "";
    for (Customer customer : clients) {
        clientInfo = clientInfo + customer.getCust() + "\n\n";
        for (Account account : customer.accounts) {
            clientInfo = clientInfo + account.getAccinfo() + "\n";
        }

    }

if(clientInfo.equals(""))
    return "Not in use";
else
   return clientInfo;
}
```

Here two things done, 1. clientInfo is declared outside forloop. 2. and return statement is after for loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is inside first loop. It should be outside. See the below code.

```
public String allAccounts()
{
    String clientInfo = "";
    for (Customer customer : clients)
    {
        clientInfo = clientInfo + customer.getCust() + "\n\n";
        for (Account account : customer.accounts)
        {
            clientInfo = clientInfo + account.getAccinfo() + "\n";
        }
    }
    if ("".equals(clientInfo))
    {
        return "Not in use";
    }
    return clientInfo;
}
```